# thresholds in roc_curve in scikit learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am referring to the below link and sample, and post the plot diagram from this page where I am confused. My confusion is, there are only 4 threshold, but it seems the roc curve has many data points (> 4 data points), wondering how roc_curve working underlying to find more data points?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#roc-metrics

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
>>> fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y, scores, pos_label=2)
>>> fpr
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ])
>>> tpr
array([ 0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ])
>>> thresholds
array([ 0.8 ,  0.4 ,  0.35,  0.1 ])
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As HaohanWang mentioned, the parameter '**drop_intermediate**' in function **roc_curve** can drop some suboptimal thresholds for creating lighter ROC curves. ([roc_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)).

If set the parameter to be False, all threshold will be displayed, for example:
[image]

all thresholds and corresponding TPRs and FPRs are calculated, but some of them are useless for plotting the ROC curve.

Comment: What is considered a sub optimal threshold?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai a suboptimal threshold corresponds to a point on the ROC curve that is colinear with adjacent points. For example, look at all the thresholds at TPR=1. They don't add anything to the ROC curve, so its simpler to interpolate between them. See the source code for more details: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L916-L932

Answer (score 1):

That plot is actually from this example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Comment: I see, thanks maxymoo. I have a general question, when we use `roc_curve` in scikit learn, I think in order to draw ROC curve, we need to select model threshold, and which reflects to related FPR and FNR. Wondering how scikie learn `roc_curve` choose threshold?

Comment: BTW, maxymoo, in your example, I think in order to draw `roc_curve`, scikit learn also need model performance of TPR and FNR for a lot of model threshold, correct? But in your example, I do not need they train model with different threshold. If you could clarify a bit more, it will be great. :)

Comment: I think the thresholds are just the distinct values of `score`

Comment: Thanks maxymoo, if you could elaborate a bit more, it will be great. I am confused by this line of code `fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])`, `y_test[:, i]` is the real result for classification, and `y_score[:, i]` is the prediction results => In the sample you mentioned (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html). For `score`, I think you mean predicted results? Which is `y_score[:, i]`, I just curious how discrete value (I think it is class label predicted results, like `0 and 1`) from y_score[:, i]

Comment: (cont'd) to draw `roc`? I think `roc` needs tpr and fpr according to different model threshold, but in this example, model only score/trained once. If I mis-understand anything, please feel free to correct me. Thanks.

Comment: see `drop_intermediate` argument of the `roc_curve` method. (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html). Basically, sometimes, sklearn decides to drop some non-useful thresholds, resulting in thresholds to be less than distinct values. @LinMa