# scikit-learn: How do I define the thresholds for the ROC curve?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

When plotting the ROC (or deriving the AUC) in `scikit-learn`, how can one *specify* arbitrary thresholds for `roc_curve`, rather than having the function calculate them internally and return them?

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
fpr,tpr,thresholds = roc_curve(y_true,y_pred)
```

A related question was asked at [Scikit - How to define thresholds for plotting roc curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657329/scikit-how-to-define-thresholds-for-plotting-roc-curve), but the OP's accepted answer indicates that their intent was different to how it was written.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get from the classifier are scores, not just a class prediction.

`roc_curve` will give you a set of thresholds with associated false positive rates and true positive rates.

If you want your own threshold, just use it:

```
y_class = y_pred > threshold
```

Then you can display a confusion matrix, with this new `y_class` compared to `y_true`.

And if you want several thresholds, do the same, and get the confusion matrix from each of them to get the true and false positive rate.

Comment: Thank you so much - this is (a) what I needed to know about `scikit-learn`'s `roc_curve` function and (b) tells me that where (in my case) I only have discrete classes rather than predicted probabilities that I must roll my own ROC curve via a set of confusion matrices. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. ROC curve shows you outputs for different thresholds. You always choose best threshold for you model to get forecasts, but ROC curve shows you how robust/good your model is for different thresholds. Here you have quite good explanation how it works: https://www.dataschool.io/roc-curves-and-auc-explained/

Comment: Thanks for the information - I was more asking how to specify arbitrary thresholds for ROC curve calculation in `scikit-learn`, rather than how ROCs and AUCs work in general.